# How can I select a default route parameter value when a user doesn't select a specific option?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my system, every user has customers - customers have a six digit number. I've setup my route so that:

http://localhost/AwesomeSite/123456/Orders

leads to the controller method (OrdersController):

```
public ActionResult Index(int customerNumber)
{
    var result = from o in orderRepository
                 where o.customerNumber == customerNumber
                 select o;

    return View(result);
}
```

How can I absolutely make sure that if the user doesn't select a specific customer of theirs, that I can specify a default route value for customerNumber which corresponds to (maybe) the customerNumber of the first customer in their list?

The reason I think I have to do this, is that a number of the options are also available through a submenu on the page (Customers -> Orders), and if the logged in user selects orders - I should have something to show them, even if it's the orders of the first customer they have.

Comment: Or, equally - what's a good pattern here? Is the issue that I'm allowing users to see links further in than they should be able to? Should I override the index method, one with no parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom model binder (IModelBinder) for the Customer object in which you will use the `customerNumber` route parameter to fetch the given customer and verify if it belongs to the currently logged in user (which you will fetch from the ControllerContext parameter that is passed to the Bind method that you will implement). If it doesn't simply return the first customer of the given user. And then:

```
public ActionResult Index(Customer customer)
{
    return View(customer);
}
```